# NSDate conversion in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am getting a `NSString Sun Feb 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`  I want to

convert that into `dd-mm-yy`  in ios . This is what i tried am not getting the output as I

wanted. Convert string to date object:

```
 NSString  *dateStr = @"Sun Feb 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) " ;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];    
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: stripped];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to remove the part `(India Standard Time)` in your `dateStr` first.

Comment: What did you get the output?

Comment: am getting nil on mydate i removed the string GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) . am not aware of changing format thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@"Sun Feb 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) "
```

Remove

```
 (India Standard Time)
```

then do the formattings

```
NSString  *dateStr = @"Sun Feb 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530" ;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE LLLL dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: ya i removed it  after that what exactly i have to do ?

Answer (score 3):

```
 NSDateFormatter *sdateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
sdateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[sdateFormatter setDateFormat:@"E MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz '(IST)'"];
NSDate *sdate = [sdateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString  *dateStr = @"Sun Feb 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) " ;
NSString *clippedString = [dateStr substringToIndex:dateStr.length - 23];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EE LLLL dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:clippedString];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *newDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: NSString *clippedString = [start substringToIndex:start.length - 23];
    
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EE LLLL dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:stripped]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
    
 but date is still nil

Comment: @user2168483 I have tested the above code, it is showing proper values.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the "GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" text,

```
    NSString  *dateStr = @"Sun Feb 24 2013 00:00:00" ;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : It worked for me

```
NSString  *dateStr = @"Sun Feb 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Comment: IF it works , you are required to mark it correct and upvote so that all knows this works and it is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString  *dateStr = @"Sun Feb 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530" ;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC+0530"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE LLL dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];


[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"date : %@",newDateString);
```